# Error Patrón REGEXP_LIKE SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, regex

Buen día.
Es mi primera vez en el foro, espero que debido a mi corta edad e inexperiencia la pregunta no sea trivial para la comunidad, tengo una consulta en SQL Oracle dónde los datos de la columna traen números separados por ";" **3;4;5;6;8;9;14** Quiero poder obtener las filas que **no** contengan el número 4, este número puede estar en cualquier posición, también exiten filas de un solo número dónde el carácter ";" no se encuentra presente, he intentado con un `NOT LIKE`en la cláusula `WHERE`, pero al estar presente el número 14 no es una opción, sin embargo, intente con la siguiente cláusula: `WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (XY.ORDER_TYPE,'^[^4]+[^;]4$')`pero no he tenido éxito, la consulta no arroja error, sin embargo, no logro obtener todas las filas que **no** contengan el número 4. De antemano agradezco la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque lo más apropiado es normalizar la tabla.
Puedes usar un truco que por medio de una *Consulta Jerárquica* obtienes una vista con un renglón por cada elemento de la cadena. A partir de ahí simplemente validar la inexistencia (`not exists`) del valor no deseado:

```
SELECT tmp.col
  FROM ( SELECT '3;4;5;6;8;9;14' col FROM dual
         UNION
         SELECT '2;4;6;8;10;12' FROM dual
         UNION
         SELECT '3;6;9;12' FROM dual
       ) tmp
  WHERE not exists ( SELECT 1
                       FROM ( SELECT to_number(regexp_substr(tmp.col,'[^;]+', 1, level)) e
                                FROM dual
                                CONNECT BY level <= regexp_count(tmp.col, ';')+1
                            ) elementos
                       WHERE elementos.e = 4
                   );
```

Resultado:

```
COL
--------
3;6;9;12
```

Comment: Buen día . Gracias por tomarse el tiempo de  responder mi pregunta, aplique la solución que usted propuso y funciono correctamente

Comment: Muy bien, interesante